# Issue with git when trying to "bower install ember-data"

Tags: git, ember.js, ember-data, bower-install

I'm having a git issue (**git ls-remote**) when trying to `bower install ember-data`

here is my trace

```
    bower ember-data#*                               cached git://github.com/components/ember-data.git#1.0.0-beta.10
    bower ember-data#*                             validate 1.0.0-beta.10 against git://github.com/components/ember-data.git#*
    bower ember-data#*                              ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/components/ember-data.git", exit code of #128
```

here is the bower json:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",

  "dependencies": {
    "ember": "1.7.0",
    "ember-data": "1.0.0-beta.10",
    "ember-data.model-fragments": "0.2.1",
    "ember-validations": "http://builds.dockyard.com.s3.amazonaws.com/ember-validations/ember-validations-latest.js"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your bower.json? Do you have a previous version of ember-data installed?

Comment: @Gorzas sure its in my edit

Comment: You should try ````bower install```` or ````bower install ember-data#1.0.0-beta.10````. Bower installs version ember-data#0.0.14, the last one set as stable, and bower may throw a conflict with version 1.0.0-beta.10.

Comment: What's with the private and resolutions, it should work without them

Comment: @PatsyIssa the resolution is needed cause there are 2 repos with the same name.

Comment: Can you remove that part, run bower install and select the repo from the cmd when prompted?

Comment: I removed them, when I run that I get: **bower ember#1.7.0                               ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/components/ember.git", exit code of #128** with no prompt

Comment: It's failing on ember now, something is off with your bower installation, what OS are you on and what version of bower do you have installed

Comment: win 7 with bower 1.3.8